# Run async method from Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

How Can i run async method from Xaml(on Click), normally i using something like this:

```
xmlns:ii="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:eii="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"

<Button Height="30" Width="200" Content="Save" >
                <ii:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <ii:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <eii:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="Saveing"/>
                    </ii:EventTrigger>
                </ii:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
```

Saveing method:

```
public async Task Saveing(){...}
```

Comment: Button has click, so there is no need for this interaction triggers, all you then do is add the async keyword to the event handler.

Comment: In mvvm application?

Comment: In that case the button can bind to a command. Command then has an Action which can be async. You can use something like Prism or MVVMLIGHT to use their commands.

Comment: @P10trek MVVM means that the controls code behind shouldn't say how it processes the data, having an event that passes the instruction to the view model is perfectly correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of MVVM is to separate the UI from the processing.

Bind the `Command` property of your button to an `ICommand` (RelayCommand or other implementation) item in your ViewModel. The associated method for this command can be called in an `async` manner. E.g.

```
public ICommand SaveCommand {get; private set;}

private async Task SaveMethodAsync() 
{
    await dbService.SaveDataAsync(modelItem).ConfigureAwait(false);
    ...
}


public ViewModel()
{
    SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(async () =>
        await SaveMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the XAML shouldn't run anything, it should just inform the view model something needs to be run, one method would be to wire up an event to on click event, however another and probably better way is to use the CommandBinding

Button has a Command Property, if you have a code object the implements ICommand then you can use the command binding to trigger the action

example

```
public interface ISavable
{
    void Save();
    SaveCommand SaveCommand { get; }
}
public class SaveCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return parameter is ISavable;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Task.Run(()=>((ISavable)parameter).Save());
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

this way any view model that implements `ISavable` will be wired up with no code behind

Answer (score 0):

> Just rewrite your method as below:

```
public void Saving() 
{
    Task.Run(async () => {...});
}
```

Comment: why would you not return a Task like in the accepted answer? What happens to exceptions on the background thread?